# Uploading varbinary using ADODB.Stream - how to use LoadFromFile if file is open on computer for inserting into SQL varbinary(max) field?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, vba, ms-access, adodb

### Goal

I am attempting to do the following from Microsoft Access:

- Insert into a SQL 2008 database a varbinary(max) field

  - Read binary file (Excel/Word)
  - Insert into SQL database

This seems like it would be straightforward.

### Background

It would appear ADODB.Stream is the best way to do this. I am not convinced this is best. Filestream is disabled on my SQL server environment.

I have written code which will accomplish what I want in VBA for all files which are *not opened*. I do not want to require users to close the files prior to reading them with VBA.

This is my current code:

```vb
Dim mStream As ADODB.Stream
Set mStream = New ADODB.Stream

Dim fName As String
fName = "C:\tmp.docx"

mStream.Type = adTypeBinary
mStream.Open
mStream.LoadFromFile fName  'this fails if the file is open

Dim mCmd As ADODB.Command
Set mCmd = New ADODB.Command

With mCmd

    ' define query
    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO testingvarbinary (testVarBinary) " & _
        "VALUES (?)"
    .CommandType = adCmdText

    ' add parameter
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@P1", adVarBinary, adParamInput, mStream.Size, mStream.Read)

End With

mCmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
mCmd.Execute
```

I've thought about trying to simply copy the file to C:\tmp or something and read that one, but it just seems like there should be a way to do this.

### Question

How can I modify the above code to work for files which a user has opened? In [this thread](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showpost.php?p=1102493&postcount=4) it seems there is a way to use the `.Open` command to do this, but I've been unsuccessful in even getting the `.Open` to return ANYTHING let alone the entire file. I've not found a single example using `Open` rather than `LoadFromFile` for an actual file on my computer.

If there is a different way in VBA than using ADODB.Stream that would be great too, I'm not tied to using it at all.

Comment: re: "it just seems like there should be a way to do this" - I'm not so sure. For example, if a Word document is open then the actual contents of the document at any given moment is some combination of what's in foo.docx, what's in ~$foo.docx, and what's in memory on the user's machine. You could copy the .docx file to %TEMP% (I just tried it and it seems to work), but it appears that *at best* you'll the last saved version of the file. Perhaps that might suffice in your case, but it seems a bit dodgy to me.

Comment: @GordThompson I'm ok with it being the last saved version, I can always prompt users something like "This will upload the last saved version." It looks like I can actually do this just reading the file in directly using `Open fName For Binary Access Read As` but this seems an awful way to do it..

Comment: In that case I'd probably just copy foo.docx to %TEMP%, `LoadFromFile` the copy, and then delete the copy.